# How to validate reCAPTCHA

Tags: php, javascript, recaptcha

I want to write a JavaScript and php validation for `reCAPTCHA` In my php I have the function below but I doesn't work. It doesn't, return an errror message if I enter the wrong `reCAPTCHA` code:

```
function invalid($inputname,$error_message)
{
    $this->js.='if (!invalid(formname.'.$inputname.',"'.$error_message.'")) return false;';
    if ( isset($_POST[$inputname]) && strlen($_POST[$inputname]) - strlen(str_replace(' ','',$_POST[$inputname])) > $limit && $_POST[$inputname] != "")
    {
        $this -> error_message .= $error_message.'<br>';
    }
}
```

I don't want to just echo the message I want to echo the message on top of the form like I did with my other validate using:

Can someone show me how to do it correctly in php and javascript?

Thanks

Comment: how are you validating the reCAPTCHA?

Comment: @Dagon i use the google tutorial for it but in that one it only echo out the message

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This

```
strlen($_POST[$inputname]) - strlen(str_replace(' ','',$_POST[$inputname])) > $limit
```

will be false, assuming $limit is something like 6. Should be just

```
strlen(str_replace(' ','',$_POST[$inputname])) > $limit
```

Let's say the captcha is "bananas". `strlen("bananas") - strlen("bananas") == 0`.

**Added** The JavaScript doesn't return `false` at any point, so it will return `undefined` if the captcha is correct, which may affect your code elsewhere (particularly if you are using === ).

Comment: thats works for the php. I have updated my question to show what i did for the javascript. can you correct me please thanks.

Comment: his code correcting worked for php so please take off the drop vote.

Comment: Thank you @AlexRuso. I've added to my answer concerning the JS.

Comment: Thank you @AlexRuso. You shouldn't really remove the JavaScript from your post though, it'll be confusing for someone reading this.

Comment: i did used the javascript. I only did the validation server side not client,

Answer (score 2):

Please read [the reCAPTCHA documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php). It clearly outlines the correct use of the `recaptcha_check_answer()` function (part of the reCAPTCHA PHP library) to validate solutions.